# SQL Server 2008 convert int to dd:hh:mm

Tags: datetime, sql-server-2008-r2, int

How can I convert an `int` value (ie: `1800`) which represents minutes into a value that looks like this: `dd:hh:mm` (`days:hours:minutes`).

So `1800` should be converted into `1:06:00` (`1 day 6 hours 0 minutes`).

In a stored procedure I have this:

```
SELECT 
    Record_ID, Project_ID, Ticket_ID, WO_Type, DC, Title, Device_Quantity, 
    Total/1440 as Total,  
    ((Total - Elapsed) - DATEDIFF(mi, Record_Time, getdate())) as FinalTimeLeft, 
    Completed 
FROM Record
```

How would I implement the casting into the SP? Above `FinalTimeLeft=1800`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this example - it does hours, minutes and seconds but it should be easy to modify for days, hours and minutes:

```
SELECT 
  CAST(mins / 3600 AS VARCHAR) + ':' + 
  RIGHT('0' + CAST((mins % 3600) / 60  AS VARCHAR), 2) + ':' +
  RIGHT('0' + CAST(mins % 60 AS VARCHAR), 2)
FROM 
  (SELECT 1800 AS mins) a
```

EDIT: Included your stored procedure with my code amended for day, hour and minute:

```
SELECT 
  *
  ,CAST(FinalTimeLeft / 1440 AS VARCHAR) + ':' +
     RIGHT('0' + CAST((FinalTimeLeft / 60) % 24 AS VARCHAR), 2) + ':' +
     RIGHT('0' + CAST(FinalTimeLeft % 60 AS VARCHAR), 2) AS duration
FROM ( 
SELECT 
  Record_ID
  ,Project_ID
  ,Ticket_ID
  ,WO_Type
  ,DC
  ,Title
  ,Device_Quantity
  ,Total/1440 as Total
  ,((Total-Elapsed)-DATEDIFF(mi,Record_Time,getdate())) as FinalTimeLeft
  ,Completed
FROM record) a
```

Comment: It's fine except that it should be 1440 instead of 3600 on the secod line :) Thanks

Comment: I have updated the original question with details on the stored procedure. How do I implement your code into that?

Comment: Works but it doesn't know what FinalTimeLeft is as that is not a column in the table. So if I substitute that for `((Total-Elapsed)-DATEDIFF(mi,Record_Time,getdate())) ` it resolves ok but it doesn't look nice

Comment: Sorry thoght FinalTimeLeft was column name - edited to use as a sub query.